# unable to send mail in c# using smtp server

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient

I have a service which is suppose to send the mail to selected users,

the service looks like below

```
try
{
    var smtpHost = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP-HOST"].ToString();//smtp.gmail.com
    var fromEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP-USER"].ToString();//My Id
    var toEmail = "ibrahim.shaikh@chromeinfosoft.com";
    var subject = "test";
    var body = "body";
    var smtpPort = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP-PORT"].ToString();//465
    var smtpPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP-PASSWORD"].ToString();//my password

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(smtpHost);
    using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpHost))
    {
        mail.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
        mail.To.Add(toEmail);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = body;
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
        SmtpServer.Port = Convert.ToInt32(smtpPort);
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromEmail, smtpPassword);

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Log the error
}
```

my config file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="SMTP-HOST" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
        <add key="SMTP-PORT" value="465"/>
        <add key="SMTP-USER" value="ibrahim.shaikh@chromeinfosoft.com"/>
        <add key="SMTP-SSL" value="N"/>
        <add key="SMTP-PASSWORD" value ="Password"/>
    </appSettings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

my outlook configuration

[image]

Now I am trying to send the mail but the exception is coming.

> exception: {"Failure sending mail."}

> inner exception: {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."}  System.Exception {System.IO.IOException}

my email Id and password is correct with port details, still the same error occurred,

any suggestions what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: U can refer to the link https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GMAIL-SMTP-Error-Failure-sending-email.aspx .

Comment: Have you tried SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true ?